# MySql, combining date and time column into a time stamp

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, timestamp

I am guessing this is relatively simple to do, but I am unsure of the syntax. I have date and time columns that I want to combine to a timestamp column. how would I query this using a select?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Mysql does not seem to have a constructor for datetime such as datetime('2017-10-26', '09:28:00').  So you will have to treat the component part as string and use string concatenation function (Note mysql does not have the || operator for string concatenation). If you want the datetime type, you will have to cast it.

```
concat(datefield,' ',timefield) as date

select cast(concat('2017-10-26', ' ', '09:28:00') as datetime) as dt;
```

Comment: I needed to use it in a constraint with todays date, this did the trick `select * from my_table where my_date = cast(concat(CURDATE(), ' ', '13:00:00') as datetime)`

Answer (score 102):

Or you could use the built-in [`TIMESTAMP(date,time)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp) function.

So then you would do something like this say from an Orders table...

```
SELECT OrderNumber, TIMESTAMP(date,time) as OrderTS, SalesPersonID
FROM Orders
```

Comment: This heavily upvoted answer looks more like a comment.  If you intend to keep this post as an answer, please take the time to beef it up so that it is not merely a link-only answer.

Answer (score 8):

If it possible to use built-in function, just use it.
Any way here is an example to find records between given timestamps.

```
SELECT `id` FROM `ar_time` WHERE TIMESTAMP(`cdate`,`ctime`) BETWEEN fromTimeStamp AND nowTimeStamp;
```

Answer (score 4):

For 24hr time

```
TIMESTAMP(Date, STR_TO_DATE(Time, '%h:%i %p'))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE TIMESTAMP(datecol, timecol) > '2015-01-01 12:00:00';
```

Answer (score 3):

O.P. did say `SELECT` but in case anyone wants to **add a timestamp column**:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `t` ADD COLUMN `stamp` TIMESTAMP;
UPDATE `t` SET `stamp` = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`Date`, ' ', `Time`), '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

Adjust [format strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6308088/673991) to taste.

Answer (score 0):

`concat('2021-12-31', ' ', '07:00:00')`

it worked in an INSERT procedure.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30570376)