# Mysql, combining date and time column in to a timestamp, when sometimes time is null

Tags: mysql

I have a problem similar to this question but with an added complication:
[MySql, combining date and time column into a time stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125931/mysql-combining-date-and-time-column-into-a-time-stamp)

I have two columns one for date and one for time and I need to combine them as a timestamp for comparison.  Setting a time is optional in our application and in some cases it's null.  If I use CONCAT it only works for the instances where the time is set.

Is the best way to do this, have two queries with a UNION?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a COALESCE to choose a default time value when yours is NULL.

```
CONCAT(datefield, ' ', COALESCE(timefield, '00:00:00')) AS date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
concat(datefield,' ',ifnull(timefield,'00:00:00')) as date
```