# Query Sql Date and Time(CLOSED)

Tags: php, sql, date

Please Help me. i have table A. date format is dd/mm/yy and time format is hh:mm:ss am/pm

```
╔══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╗
║   DATE   ║    TIME     ║    PHONE    ║ MESSAGE ║
╠══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╣
║ 25/09/07 ║ 01:57:55 PM ║ 62856979898 ║ Tes a   ║
║ 25/09/07 ║ 04:56:51 PM ║ 62856123467 ║ Tes B   ║
╚══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╝
```

How query to find data where date between time.

Comment: How can you take a date, and compare it with time?

Comment: What type is date field?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125931/mysql-combining-date-and-time-column-into-a-time-stamp

Comment: I think this question not deserve down-vote!

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the disadvantages of not storing the data type properly on the database. Dates should be stored as `DATE` or `DATETIME`.

If you are using `MySQL`, you can use `STR_TO_DATE` which converts string into date,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date, ' ', time), '%d/%m/%y %h:%i:%s %p') 
        BETWEEN '2007-09-25 13:00:00' AND '2007-09-25 14:00:00'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0e62/2)
- [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╗
║   DATE   ║    TIME     ║    PHONE    ║ MESSAGE ║
╠══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╣
║ 25/09/07 ║ 01:57:55 PM ║ 62856979898 ║ Tes a   ║
╚══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╝
```

Some disadvantages of your current design:

- cannot directly compare dates and times
- cannot use index
- etc ...

Answer (score 0):

use `BETWEEN` keyword

```
 "SELECT * FROM table_A WHERE date BETWEEN '" . $from_date . "' AND  '" . $to_date . "'"
```

Comment: Those dont look like date fields. Also, it is better to use prepared statements.