# Change date while preserving time

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update a bunch of dates in a MySQL table while preserving the time portion of the date. For example, I join like this:

```
select crt.StartTime, crt.EndTime, crs.WorkDate
from CrewReportTimesheet crt
join CrewReportSummary crs
on crt.CrewReportSummaryID = crs.CrewReportSummaryID
```

`crt.StartTime` and `crt.EndTime` have wrong dates but correct times. `crs.WorkDate` has the right date but no times. So for all records that match the above join, I need to set `crt.StartTime` and `crt.EndTime` to the same date as `crs.WorkDate` while preserving the times in those columns.

Here's an example of the bad data:

[image]

Notice the first 2 columns with timestamps. Time is right, date is wrong. Cells A1 and B1 should be 2015-12-19 just like C1. And so on.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show some sample data? just few rows what would be the result you desire?

Comment: @JorgeCampos I posted some sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `UPDATE` statement along with an `INNER JOIN` to choose the records you want to update.

```
UPDATE CrewReportTimesheet crt
    INNER JOIN CrewReportSummary crs
    ON crt.CrewReportSummaryID = crs.CrewReportSummaryID
SET crt.StartTime = TIMESTAMP(DATE(crs.WorkDate), TIME(crt.StartTime)),
    crt.EndTime   = TIMESTAMP(DATE(crs.WorkDate), TIME(crt.EndTime))
```

If you want to use `CONCAT()` instead you can try the following:

```
UPDATE CrewReportTimesheet crt
    INNER JOIN CrewReportSummary crs
    ON crt.CrewReportSummaryID = crs.CrewReportSummaryID
SET crt.StartTime = CONCAT(DATE(crs.WorkDate), ' ', TIME(crt.StartTime)),
    crt.EndTime   = CONCAT(DATE(crs.WorkDate), ' ', TIME(crt.EndTime))
```

Comment: I think this isn't what He wants, It would be something like concatenate the date and the time to create the new start and end as datetime of course

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125931/mysql-combining-date-and-time-column-into-a-time-stamp).  It seems MySQL has a `TIMESTAMP` function which can do the heavy lifting, and I'd rather rely on this than formatting, the latter which is prone to error.

Comment: @JorgeCampos could you post an answer with the sql using concat() and date_format()? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @SweatCoder Tim already did it: comment above: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4125957/460557

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen your update throws a syntax error: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'crt.EndTime   = CONCAT(DATE(crs.WorkDate), ' ', TIME(crt.EndTime))' at line 5 0.000 sec` -- any ideas?

Comment: Sorry there were commas missing.  Try it again.  You need to use `UPDATE...SET c1 = v1, c2 = v2`

Comment: Bingo. Thanks so much Tim and Jorge. FYI: I used the second update, didn't try the first.