# Date Conversion in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a string like this "Fri Apr 06 02:28:41 2012", how can i convert it to YYYY-mm-dd format using MySQL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296725/parse-date-in-mysql

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: The MySQL date format is actually YYYY-MM-DD, but using the str_to_date() and date_format() functions you can accept and generate any date format required. 

View this link for more information : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Fri Apr 06, 02:28:41 2012','%W %M %d, %H:%i:%s %Y');
```