# INSERT into DB DateTime string

Tags: mysql

I have the string `04/04/2012 04:03:35 AM`. How can I convert it and insert into a table? Field type is `datetime`.

Comment: it`s return empty string

Comment: `cast ('04/04/2012 04:03:35 AM') as datetime`?

Comment: Post the Insert SQL you are using.

Comment: Downvoters care to explain?  It's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @eggyal Please refer to the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, i am sure there is a clause there that say provide example of what you have tried first and make sure you search for your answer prior to asking, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296725/parse-date-in-mysql

Comment: @Churk: And yet you commented first, with an unhelpful and incorrect response; surely better to have said then exactly what you just did to me?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
STR_TO_DATE('04/04/2012 04:03:35 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %r')
```

Or, better yet, present your literal in [a format MySQL expects](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html) (e.g. `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm`).