# Convert string to MySQL date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need to be able to convert a string (see example below) to a format that can be added to MySQL.  I could just add it as a var car but I need to be able to run queries based on these date ranges.

e.g. '02 May 2013 12:08 AM GMT'

Any suggestion of the best way to achieve this?

**EDIT**
Currently trying the following:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d M Y H:i A e', '02 May 2013 12:08 AM GMT');
echo $date;
```

but getting a server error when I trying echoing the date.

I've also tried the following to break the date and timezone apart and try to deal with it separately:

```
$myvalue = '02 May 2013 12:08 AM GMT';
$arr = explode(' ',trim($myvalue));
$timezone = new DateTimeZone($arr[5]);
$arr[count($arr)-1]='';
$time=implode(' ',$arr);
$date = date_create_from_format('d M Y h:i A', $time, $timezone);
echo $date;
```

but again I'm getting a server error.

**EDIT**
I just realized that the second chunk of code might be going wrong due to the GMT as it doesn't appear to be a usable format with this function.

**EDIT**
After further investigation I think the best way to store the data is to have all dates stored as a `DATETIMEin` MySQL with the same timezone (gmt) and along with it storing the actual timezone they are and using the timezone when running queries if needed.

```
$myvalue = '02 May 2013 12:08 AM GMT';
$arr = explode(' ',trim($myvalue));
$timezone = new DateTimeZone($arr[5]);
$arr[count($arr)-1]='';
$time=implode(' ',$arr);
$timestamp = strtotime($time);
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
echo $date;
```

Comment: For everything but the timezone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539154/insert-into-db-datetime-string For the timezone: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz So you will have to split the string by timezone and not timezone first. Or if timezone never varies, you can just ignore it.

Comment: none of those links on the right are any help?

Comment: Which errors do you get? `A server error` does not help anyone. The exact error message is much more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do this, then?

```
function convertToMysqlTime($string){
    $seconds = strtotime($string);
    if (!$seconds) return false;
    return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $seconds);
}

echo convertToMysqlTime('02 May 2013 12:08 AM GMT');
```

It accounts for that GMT part, too.

Comment: There is an error in this function.  You are performing a double conversion of strtotime.  Your function should end with "return date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$seconds);"

Comment: Whoa. I don't know _how_ that happened! :) Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DateTime class createFromFormat function. If your PHP version <= 5.3. Here's the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

**Edit:**

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y H:i A e','02 May 2013 12:08 AM GMT');
echo $date->getTimeZone()->getName(); //return 'UTC'
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // return 2013-05-02 00:08
```

Set the session [timezone](http://sitepoint.com/synchronize-php-mysql-timezone-configuration) in mysql:

Comment: this seems to be the ticket.  the only thing i've realised is that the timezone will matter so I will need to adjust the time to GMT time depending on the timezone.  Is this possible without a messy if/else or switch?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean. Your format is: d M Y H:i A e
Your timezone is UTC (e).

Comment: $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y H:i A e','02 May 2013 12:08 AM GMT');
echo $date->getTimeZone()->getName(); //return 'UTC'
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // return 2013-05-02 00:08

Set the session timezone in mysql: http://www.sitepoint.com/synchronize-php-mysql-timezone-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want to convert date obtained from javascript "Date()" function.
consider this function in javascript part:

```
function ISODateString(d) // to get date in format that MySQL accepts
{
  function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
  return d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'
      + pad(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'
      + pad(d.getUTCDate()) +' '
      + pad(d.getUTCHours())+':'
      + pad(d.getUTCMinutes())+':'
      + pad(d.getUTCSeconds())
}
```

after this use:

```
var d=ISODateString(new Date())
```

now to send it either use post method or GET with url encoding to utf-8

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d M Y H:i A e', '02 May 2013 12:08 AM GMT');
echo $date;
```

This code will always produce error messages, for different reasons.

If the PHP version is < 5.3 then the code will fail, because `date_create_from_format()` does not exist.

If the PHP version is >= 5.3 then the second line will fail, because `$date` is an instance of `DateTime` and that class does not have a `__toString()` method. Use [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `strtotime()` to convert a textual representation of a time (such as your example) to a Unix timestamp:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($string);
```

Then you can store this value in MySQL's `TIMESTAMP` field type.