# MySQL ORDER BY Date field which is not in date format

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field containing dates in this format DD/MM/YYYY and I need to order the results DESC by this field, but it is saved as a VARCHAR and I cannot change this. Is there a workaround?

There really is no way for me to change the field type so please don't say this is a bad way to do this as I already know. I just need to know if it is possible.

Thanks for any help and advice in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296725/parse-date-in-mysql

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do it by the following way,

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(yourDate,'%d-%m-%Y') DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `STR_TO_DATE`:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

```
...
order by str_to_date(myCol, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Exactly same as @PSR **`:)`**

Answer (score 1):

Use `STR_TO_DATE()` MySQL function:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(your_date_column, '%d/%M/%Y') DESC;
```

*sidenote:* `STR_TO_DATE` converts String to Date while `DATE_FORMAT` converts Date to String

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you stored date in your date field. In my case, it is separated by "/" so I used -

```
...
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(report_date, '%m/%d/%Y') DESC;
```

In case, if you're using "-" to separate date, month and year, then you can use -

```
...
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(report_date, '%m-%d-%Y') DESC;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this

[**STR_TO_DATE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
   SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY  STR_TO_DATE(date_field, '%d-%M-%Y') DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY CONCAT(SUBSTR(field, 7, 4), SUBSTR(field, 4, 2), SUBSTR(field, 1, 2)) DESC
```