# How do I query posts and use the 'orderby' attribute to order posts in loop according to date 'meta_value'?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, meta-key

I am creating a website for a theatre company, and I am creating an index of all past, current, and future productions. I would like the index to 'orderby' the ending date of each production (ACF 'date' field type; 'ending_date').

Here is an example of my query:

```
 <?php 
  $futureProd = array(
   'post_type' => 'productions',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'meta_key' => 'ending_date',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value',
   'order' => 'ASC',
 );

 $slider_posts = new WP_Query($futureProd);

 $array_rev = array_reverse($slider_posts->posts);
 $slider_posts->posts = $array_rev;

 ?>
```

Have also tried the following, adding the 'meta_value_date' as well as 'meta_value_num' alternatives:

```
<?php // query posts
  $futureProd = array(
    'post_type' => 'productions',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'ending_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_date',            
    'order' => 'ASC',
  );
?>
```

AND

```
<?php // query posts
      $futureProd = array(
    'post_type' => 'productions',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'ending_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',            
    'order' => 'ASC',
  );
?>
```

No matter what I try, the posts refuse to order themselevs by the meta_value, and instead opt to order themselves by the default, post date.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> You can spicify the datatype in `orderby` key like `meta_value_*`
>   possible values are 'NUMERIC', 'BINARY', 'CHAR', 'DATE', 'DATETIME',
>   'DECIMAL', 'SIGNED', 'TIME', 'UNSIGNED'.

Try this,

```
$futureProd = array(
    'post_type' => 'productions',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'ending_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);

$slider_posts = new WP_Query($futureProd);
```

Please Note: for above code to work you need to have date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format if you have date in different format then you have to create your custom filter function hook in to [`posts_orderby`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby) filter with [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) MySQL function.

---

**For date format YYYYMMDD**

Add this in your active theme `function.php` file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.

```
function text_domain_posts_orderby($orderby, $query) {
    //Only for custom orderby key
    if ($query->get('orderby') != 'yyyymmdd_date_format')
        return $orderby;
    if (!( $order = $query->get('order') ))
        $order = 'ASC';
    global $wpdb;
    $fieldName = $wpdb->postmeta . '.meta_value';
    return "STR_TO_DATE(" . $fieldName . ", '%Y%m%d') " . $order;
}

add_filter('posts_orderby', 'text_domain_posts_orderby', 10, 2);
```

So now your WP_Query argument should look like this:

```
$futureProd = array(
    'post_type' => 'productions',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'ending_date',
    'orderby' => 'yyyymmdd_date_format', //added custom orderby key
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
```

**The code is tested and fully functional.**

Reference:

- [WP_Query Order & Orderby Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)
- [MySQL ORDER BY Date field which is not in date format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16936239/5019802)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Gave it a try. Problem persists. :(

Any other ideas?

Comment: What is the date format you are using? Is it `YYYY-MM-DD` ?

Comment: I've got it returning YYYYMMDD so that it comes out as an 8 digit number. i.e January 1, 2017 returns: 20170101.

Comment: @JamieCavanagh: I have update my answer. please read the note section and you have to use code under `For date format YYYYMMDD` section.

Comment: Hey Raunak. So sorry but this didn't work either. :(

Comment: @JamieCavanagh: I have tested my code it is working fine; there must be an issue with your date format; are you 100% sure you date format is `YYYYMMDD` ?

Comment: Thank you @RaunakGupta You are amazing. There are thousands of articles with meta fields with wrong date format. Everyone who sees this comment must know that this is the only complete answer I could find on the Internet so please give an up vote :)