# Sort by Date Advance Custom Fields custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently had a list of events that where in date order and worked fine due to the format being numeric, but the client has since changed the output format and now I'm struggling to list out the events in and Ascending date order, this is the new format:

```
    <?php 

    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page'    => 100,
        'meta_key'          => 'location',          
        'post_type'         => 'events_col',
        'offset'            => 1,
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    ));

    if( $posts ): ?>
```

Here is the output:

```
<div><?php echo date("l dS F Y",strtotime(get_field('date'))); ?></div>
```

the output is all a bit of a jumble I am not even sure what the order is as is illogical!

Comment: Can you update your question with what format you have in `date` meta field. or you can check this answer for an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/41542520/5019802

Comment: the other question will do it! Thanks!