# Sort advanced custom post types by Date

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

Here is the thing. I have a custom post type (klassenaktivitäten) which has a custom field named as 'year' which is a custom field of type Datepicker. Now the Problem. I want to list all klassenaktivitäten as follows:

2017

- Klassenaktivitäten 1 (jahre == 2017)
- Klassenaktivitäten 2 (jahre == 2017)
- Klassenaktivitäten 3 (jahre == 2017)
- .......

2016

- Klassenaktivitäten 1 (jahre == 2016)
- Klassenaktivitäten 2 (jahre == 2016)
- Klassenaktivitäten 3 (jahre == 2016)

Comment: check this answer this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/41542520/5019802

Comment: I checked the answer. It was of no help to me. Thanks anyway.