# Orderby ACF custom field date don't work

Tags: wordpress, date, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I view the other post but I found nothing, I'm on since 3 days :

I want display 3 'evenements' in the order `ASC`
but 2018 is always before 2017

```
$auj = date('Ymd');

$queryEvent = new WP_Query(
    array(
    'category_name' => 'evenements',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'meta_key' => 'date_de_fin',
    'orberby' => 'meta_key',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'date_de_fin',
            'value' => $auj,
            'compare' => '>=',
        ),
    )
    )
);

?>
```

someone has an idea ?

Comment: what is the date format of `date_de_fin`, if it is not in Y-m-d, then check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41542520/5019802.

Comment: the format is Ymd and i try your code and the order display is the same :/

Comment: can you post your updated code and also some sample value of `date_de_fin`.

Comment: done beside with a capture of the echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve by problem with a SQL query :

```
   $queryEvent = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM cci_posts INNER JOIN cci_postmeta ON cci_posts.id = cci_postmeta.post_id INNER JOIN cci_term_relationships ON  cci_posts.id = cci_term_relationships.object_id WHERE cci_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 4 AND cci_postmeta.meta_key = "date_de_fin" AND cci_postmeta.meta_value > 20170221 AND cci_posts.post_status = "publish" ORDER BY cci_postmeta.meta_value ASC LIMIT 3', OBJECT );
                        //$queryEvent = new WP_Query($args);
                        ?>
                        <?php if ( $queryEvent ) : ?>

                        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                        <?php foreach ($queryEvent as $post) {
                          setup_postdata($post); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code .Please try your updated query.

```
<?php $auj = date('Ymd');

$queryEvent = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'category_name' => 'evenements',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'meta_key' => 'date_de_fin',
        'orberby' => 'meta_value_num', 
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'date_de_fin',
                'value'   => $auj,
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'DATE'
             ),
        )
    ));
?>
```

I have replace 'orderby' value & added 'type' parameter in meta_query.

Hope, this may be helpful to you.

Comment: your code is online, 0 changements, but thank you for your try

Comment: Have you installed any plugin for ordering posts?

Comment: And please also tell what is the return or save format in your 'date_de_fin' custom field.

Comment: Ymd et no i hav'nt instal plugin

Answer (score 0):

> As your date format is not in `Y-m-d` so you need to define your own
>   logic for shorting

```
function wh_posts_orderby($orderby, $query) {
    //Only for custom orderby key
    if ($query->get('orderby') != 'yyyymmdd_date_format')
        return $orderby;
    if (!( $order = $query->get('order') ))
        $order = 'ASC';
    global $wpdb;
    $fieldName = $wpdb->postmeta . '.meta_value';
    return "STR_TO_DATE(" . $fieldName . ", '%Y%m%d') " . $order;
}

add_filter('posts_orderby', 'wh_posts_orderby', 10, 2);
```

*Add the ^^above code to your active theme `functions.php` file.*

---

Now you can sort your post by date (format YYYYMMDD)

```
$auj = date('Ymd');
$args = [
    'category_name' => 'evenements',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'meta_key' => 'date_de_fin',
    'orberby' => 'yyyymmdd_date_format', //check this line
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND', //added this
        [
            'key' => 'date_de_fin',
            'value' => $auj,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ],
    ]
];
$queryEvent = new WP_Query($args);
if ($queryEvent->have_posts()) :
    /* Start the Loop */
    while ($queryEvent->have_posts()) : $queryEvent->the_post();

    //you post

    endwhile;
endif;
```

Related answer [How do I query posts and use the 'orderby' attribute to order posts in loop according to date 'meta_value'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41542520/5019802)

Hope this helps!

Comment: i saw this topic and  tried, i retry today the code is online : http://lpb.cerealog.net/cote-image/cci-site-alternance/ nothing as change :/ i have really no idea :(