# Query post_meta date instead of post_date_gmt

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, date, strtotime

I'm limiting my query to use show post from 6 months ago which works fine.

But I need it to be based on a date that is in the `post_meta` table instead of 'post_date_gmt'.

In my case I have meta_keys are called **`payment_date`** and the values are of course a date like **`31-10-2016`** for example.

```
$months_ago = 6;
$args = array(
'date_query' => array(
    array(
        'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
        'after'  => $months_ago . ' months ago',
        )
    ),
'numberposts'   => -1
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First thing first `date_query` works on `post_date_gmt`. If you want
>   to query post from meta fields then you have to use [`meta_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Here is a sample code:

```
$months_ago = 6;
$args = [
    //...
    //...
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // Unlimited posts
    //...
    //...
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key' => 'payment_date',
            'value' => date('d-m-Y', strtotime($months_ago . ' months ago')), //<-- Converting date into your custom date format
            'compare' => '>', //you can also use <=, >=, <, etc..
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ],
    ]
];

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) :
    /* Start the Loop */
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

    //you post

    endwhile;
endif;
```

*The above code should work for you.*

Related Question:

- [Hide past events posts based on custom date field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42954234/5019802)
- [Orderby ACF custom field date don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42325398/5019802)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Check it here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

If you scroll the examples, you'll see:

> Display posts where the custom field key is a set date and the custom field value is now. Displays only posts which date has not passed.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'    => 'event',
    'meta_key'     => 'event_date',
    'meta_value'   => date( "Ymd" ), // change to how "event date" is stored
    'meta_compare' => '>',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

In your case you could put something like: `date( "dmY", strtotime( '6 months ago' ) )`

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
$sixmonthagodate = date( "d-m-Y", strtotime('-6 Months') );

$args = array(
    'post_type'    => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key'     => 'payment_date',
    'meta_value'   => $sixmonthagodate,
    'meta_compare' => '>',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

check that if your post_type is true in your WordPress site.