# How to order DATETIME rows with [] in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql "users" table like this example:

```
id  | user    | created
100 | user001 | [27-01-2016 04:30 PM]
101 | user005 | [19-05-2017 09:28 AM]
102 | user019 | [09-10-2015 03:29 PM]
103 | user029 | [18-11-2017 05:40 PM]
```

And I want to get this table in descending order by created row like this:

```
id  | user    | created
103 | user029 | [18-11-2017 05:40 PM]
101 | user005 | [19-05-2017 09:28 AM]
100 | user001 | [27-01-2016 04:30 PM]
102 | user019 | [09-10-2015 03:29 PM]
```

I tried with DATE_FORMAT:

```
SELECT id,user,DATE_FORMAT(created,"%d %m %Y") AS created FROM users ORDER by created desc
```

But it shows nothing, how can I get it?

I'd like some help.

Comment: You need [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) instead of `DATE_FORMAT`. But it would be better to use DATETIME or TIMESTAMP for your column instead of string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ORDER BY Date field which is not in date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936181/mysql-order-by-date-field-which-is-not-in-date-format)

Comment: @NekoLopez Are your columns `DATETIME` as it says in the question? If they are not then I will delete my asnwer and check the link above.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Actually, he needs both. `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse the date and order it, `DATE_FORMAT()` to display the output in a different format.

Comment: @Barmar I don't see anything about "display the output in a different format" in the question. The expected result has the same format as original data.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Good point, I wonder why he used `DATE_FORMAT` in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Alright I got it, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
SELECT `id`, `user`, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(MID(`created`, 2, 19), '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i %p'), '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i %p') 
AS `created:`  FROM `users` ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`created:`,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i %p') DESC
```

Here is a working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72b0ac/48).

**Explanation:**

The `MID()` MySQL function returns the middle part of a string, so we easily stripped out the `[]`. After that, the `STR_TO_DATE()` function parses the returned `string` into `DATETIME` format (the `%p` is for `AM/PM`). The returning value is not properly formatted, at least not in the way you would wish to have it. So we then use `DATE_FORMAT()` to format the output. In the end, we use `STR_TO_DATE()` once again for the ordering since `created:` is returned as `string`.

I also changed your `created` output column to `created:` since it will not work if they are all the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Your `created` date format isn't correct, you should alter the table and change the field from varchar/char(string) to `timestamp` type. I have already tried converting your string dates with '[STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)' but it returns `null` because the format doesn't match either `timestamp`, `date` or `time` formats. Its always best practice to store dates/datetime as either `date` or `timestamp` data types. You can always apply formatting functions later in query to output dates to any desired format.