# how to make sql query to split database string into 3 different parts and compare them?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

what I am trying to do is: sort people in database after date of birth (nvarchar, not date type) the date is in this string format: dd-MM-yyyy  and by Sort, i mean return a list of all the people, but sorted after the date of birth, to Fill a datagridview.

I have a column with the date of birth, which is nvarchar. I want to store the day, the month and the year in 3 variables in the sql query, and also test them in order to put them in order.

what I tried is:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(date_of_birth,0,2) FROM people AS zi;
SUBSTRING(date_of_birth,3,2) AS luna
SUBSTRING(date_of_birth,6,4) AS an
SELECT [id], [specie], [sex], [date_of_birth], [greutate] FROM [people] WHERE
```

but I really don't know how to figure it out from now on...

Comment: Why not just parse it as a date if it's really a date?  see:  `STR_TO_DATE()` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296725/parse-date-in-mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  [id], [specie], [sex], [date_of_birth], [greutate],
  SUBSTRING(date_of_birth,6,4)  AS [an],
  SUBSTRING(date_of_birth,3,2)  AS [luna],
  SUBSTRING(date_of_birth,0,2)  AS [zi]
FROM
  [people]
ORDER BY
  SUBSTRING(date_of_birth,6,4),
  SUBSTRING(date_of_birth,3,2),
  SUBSTRING(date_of_birth,0,2)
```

Many RDBMS also allow this...

```
SELECT
  [id], [specie], [sex], [date_of_birth], [greutate],
  SUBSTRING(date_of_birth,6,4)  AS [an],
  SUBSTRING(date_of_birth,3,2)  AS [luna],
  SUBSTRING(date_of_birth,0,2)  AS [zi]
FROM
  [people]
ORDER BY
  [an], [luna], [zi]
```

Comment: "Many RDBMS also allow this..." (Yep, even MySQL)

Comment: would something change if I want to order the people by their age? what should I calculate or... ?

Comment: @HoreaMihuţ - Ordering by DoB is mathematically the same as ordering by age...  Someone who is older has a DoB longer ago...

Comment: I've tried it, and only checked if the year is sorted ok, but it's not. I've put exactly your code in the query.

Comment: @HoreaMihuţ - Have you checked that your substrings are correct?  *(I copied them from your code, but I suspect that they're slightly out.)*

Comment: I checked, and they are correct, if the numbering starts from 0.

Comment: i've posted them as an answer.. couldn't get much editing in here (is that what you asked for? sorry if I didn't understood right)

Comment: @HoreaMihuţ - Including the three substring fields? :)  *(Also, you should be able to edit your question, and add the example data there?)*

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you want me to do with the three substring fields? :-s

Comment: ok, so no ideea why does it not work? the substrings are ok... the date string is 12-12-2013 and we take starting from 0, 2 digits for the day, starting from 3, 2 digits for the month. and starting from 6, 4 digits for the year.

Comment: @HoreaMihuţ - Are you ***certain*** that SUBSTRING() is 0 based in MySQL?  You even said you checked.  Try looking at this link...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/19154  Your `SUBSTRING()` formula are wrong...

Comment: you are perfectly right! I'm sorry for insisting on my stupidity :)

Comment: thank you a lot MatBailie!! I just runned the query and now works perfect, as you said. Have a great day! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

.

```
SELECT
[id], [specie], [sex], [date_of_birth], [greutate]
From
[People]
ORDER BY
Convert(DateTime, date_of_birth, 105) Asc
```

.

.

By converting the column into DateTime type 105, you can get it to a format of 'dd-MM-yyyy'

Paste this code as it is and try..