# Setting the Mysql DateFormat

Tags: mysql

I want to change the data format in the mysql database like in this format 'April 11, 1979' this is what i got from the facebook API while retrieving from the facebook

So how to set the date format (April 11, 1979) while creating the mysql table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the way that mysql store dates, instead you can change the date format returned from facebook and then store it in `MYSQL`, you can do something like this:

```
$fb_date = strtotime($date_returned_from_facebook);
$insert_in_my_sql = date('Y-m-d',$fb_date);
```

read more about PHP date: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I am using Facebook API in perl so i want to insert the records from perl .

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to accept something like the specified string as a date imput format then this might help (see here: [Parse date in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296725/parse-date-in-mysql)):

```
STR_TO_DATE('April 11, 1979', '%M %e, %Y') AS date
```

With date formats explained here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STR_TO_DATE` function for this.

```
INSERT INTO test 
VALUES (1, STR_TO_DATE('April 11, 1979', '%M %d,%Y') ) ;
```

Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db30d/1