# Take PHP variable value of 201501 for example and display January 2015

Tags: php

I have a date value that is being passed as 201501.

How could I take that and display January 2015 instead?

It's being passed through a PHP variable.

Comment: [Parse date in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296725/parse-date-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$input  = '201501';
$output = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ym', $input)->format('F Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$data = '201501';

$monthNum = substr($data,4);
$year = substr($data,0,4);

$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);

$monthName = $dateObj->format('F'); 

echo $monthName.' '.$year;
```