# How to parse English string dates in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

In my SQL database `Valid Up To : Thursday, January 01, 2015 3:17 AM` is stored as string with column name `valid time`. Now I want to select data which are updated in last one hour. How can I make a suitable query?

Comment: It would be ideal if you could convert the type of this to `DATETIME`, as it will make temporal data easier to work with. Is that possible in this application? Why do you store the string "Valid Up To" as well? It would make much more sense to omit that, since the only purpose of this field is a validity timestamp.

Comment: Actually database was made by someone else it is storing as string though a c# program. now i want to handle with this database without disturbing its originality.

Comment: Fair enough. Well, you can start by searching for the things you need (as I have done for you just now, in this very site). Trim out the "Valid Up To : " string using [MySQL's replace function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956993/mysql-string-replace). Then you can search for [MySQL date parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296725/parse-date-in-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string and convert it to a date with `STR_TO_DATE()`. Parsing options are described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

```
SELECT
*
FROM your_table
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`valid time`, 'Valid Up To : %W, %M %d, %Y %l:%m %p') >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
```