# Select mysql date range based on a VARCHAR Date

Tags: php, mysql

What I am up to here is fetching some data from mysql table within a week from today. My only challange is that Dates are stored in VARCHAR format D M d Y.

My table stored `Date` example: **Wed Jul 03 2016**

***My Code is:***

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con," SELECT * FROM `BIMTECH_academy_2016_classes` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%D %M %d %Y') > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) ORDER BY Date,From DESC; ");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
          echo $row['ClassNumber'];
          echo $row['CourseName'];
          echo $row['Date'];
          echo $row['From'];
          echo $row['To'];
    }
```

[image: My Current Table]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296725/parse-date-in-mysql

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? What does `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%D %M %d %Y') FROM BIMTECH_academy_2016_classes` show? (Can't you just fix the database column type?)

Comment: You could try using the MySQL **[date_format](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)** function to format your dates.

Comment: So, how can I convert this date formt (Wed Jul 03 2016) into this (YYYY-MM-DD) using PHP?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's... well, a bit sad. Dates should be stored as proper data type because you can query the data without too much overhead. If there's any chance, please do convert those dates to valid date format and change the column type to `date` or `datetime`.

In the meantime, you can use MySQL's [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function, but since it would be used in `WHERE` part of the query, then MySQL will always scan the entire table, then internally convert all strings to dates, and only then compare with what you need. If there's a lot of data stored in a table, that can be really slow. Indexing the column won't help either, since MySQL has to fetch and convert all columns anyway before it's able to perform the comparison.

Comment: Exactly. At least use a `DATE` and a `TIME` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html ... I mean not even do that, but at least.

Answer (score 0):

example:
just relace @date with your column name and you should get the date returned in format you want.

```
SET @date = "Sun Jul 10 2016";
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(@date,"%a %b %d %Y"),"%Y-%m-%d") as formatted_date
```

more details: [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format),[STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)