# how could i get date from varchar column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get date from VARCHAR column.

(eg: 4/14/2018 12:00:00 AM)

How do I display only date

(eg: 4/14/2018)?

```
SELECT date(created_at) from self_balance
```

here created_at(varchar)

this returns NULL value

Comment: If it's a date / datetime, why is the column a varchar?

Comment: because i could not insert AM/PM to a datetime column

Comment: So? The DB uses 24hr time. If you want AM / PM in output, you can output whatever format you want after retrieving it.

Comment: use STR_TO_DATE like: SELECT STR_TO_DATE('4/14/2018 12:00:00AM','%m/%d/%Y') from dual

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse date in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296725/parse-date-in-mysql)

Comment: @Jonnix date("Y-m-d h:i:s A") in this format  i am inserting to the column

Comment: Right? But you don't have to. You could have inserted in the expected datetime format, into a datetime field. BUT, you have an alternative answer, so it's just for information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this query to get your output,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m-%d") FROM  
self_balance
```

First I am matching date format and converting it to date and then formatting.

Comment: it returns NULL

Comment: @muhammedshanid Now check. I made changes

Comment: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d"),  
"%Y-%m-%d") FROM self_balance thank you...  this query worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch date like a normal string from the database then you need to use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) which parses an English textual DateTime into a Unix timestamp. Then you can use 
[date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function which returns the formatted date string. 
I have passed a static string. You can pass your string variable which you are fetching from the database
`$time = strtotime($date_string_from_database);`

```
<?php
$time = strtotime('4/14/2018 12:00:00 AM');

$newformat = date('m/d/Y',$time);

echo $newformat;
?>
```

You can see the live demo [here](https://3v4l.org/qdOts)